# Index of a python3 for loop is behaving unusually

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, stack

I am trying to execute the following Python code:

```
arr = [3, 4, 1, 6, 2]
n = len(arr)
res = [1] * n
stack = [-1]
#left
for i in range(n):
    print(i)
    while len(stack) > 1 and arr[stack[-1]] < arr[i]:
        stack.pop()
    res[i] += i - stack[-1] - 1
    stack.append(i)
```

Although I am not changing the value of `i` inside the code it is printing as follows:

```
0
1
0
2
3
2
1
4
```

Any idea about why it is behaving like this? Python 3.6.9 is the compiler.

Edit: Adding screenshot as the reference.
[image: Python3 interactive]

Comment: What is this code doing? Please don't make us decipher the code intent.

Comment: @Jab I think, what this code is doing is not relevant here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're running this interactively. What you're seeing is the return value of the `stack.pop()` interleaved with your explicit `print()` statements.

If you assign (and ignore) the return value of the pop, you'll get the output you expect.

Comment: Thank you. You are right. Running it from a file solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I copied and pasted your code, it runs fine for me both on 3.9 and on a [3.6 online editor](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python3_online.php), not sure why you are getting a problem though.

My output for both is

```py
0
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: I think the interactive mode was the problem. Running the code after saving it to a file solves the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your code its ok.
I check it with the version 3.6.9

[image]

Comment: Thank you. My problem was running it to the interactive mode.